# Двоеточие после обощающего слова

Tags: пунктуация

Столкнулась с предложением, в котором идет сначала перечисление, потом обобщающее слово для последующей части однородных членов, сами однородные члены - и потом еще ряд однородных членов, не связанных с этим обобщающим словом. Как оформить? Допустимо ли оформление просто через запятую, без двоеточия? Или поставить двоеточие, а после однородных членов "а также" и продолжить предложение перечислением уже других одн. чл.?

Его семью: жену (...), дочерей (...) и (...), а также сотрудников его лаборатории и сотрудников (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Союз "также" - это соединительный союз, связывающий однородные члены, так что знаки препинания ставим в соответствии с известным правилом: после обобщаюего слова - двоеточие, а после однородных членов перед продолжением предложения - тире.

Comment: Спасибо. Так и хотела, только сомневалась.

Answer (score 1):

По Розенталю      (http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm) :

Если постановка запятой требуется структурой последней части предложения (стоящей после перечисления), то тире опускается и ставится только запятая, например: Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мед и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки... (Гоголь).

В Вашем примере продолжение тоже начинается с противительного союза А, значит, запятая обязательна, а тире опускается.
Его семью: жену (...), дочерей (...) и (...), а также сотрудников его лаборатории и сотрудников (...)

Comment: А имеет ли значение то, что перед словами "его семью" идет просто перечисление имен: "... издатели искренне благодарят такого-то, такого-то, его семью..."

Comment: Имеет. Нужно было привести предложение полностью.Здесь уместнее тире "Издатели искренне благодарят ..., ..., его семью... - жену (...), дочерей (...) и (...), а также сотрудников его лаборатории и сотрудников (...)" Это приложение, носящее пояснительный характер с более конкретным значением, второе тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения-пояснения ставится запятая.

Comment: Спасибо большое.